# Do all WiFi printers allow for a method of printing from the web?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, remote

Wifi printers - good job if you don't like kicking against your printer under your desk.

Can you also print from a remote location on the web with them generally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, the answer is generally no.

The device will be physically (well wireless-ly!) connected to your network and only devices on your network will be able to print to it.

If you have VPN or some sort of remote access utility that gets on to your network, you should be able to.

Also, on thinking about it you could probably forward certain ports from the internet to the printer and then print from anywhere by using your internet IP as the address of the printer (you will need nat loopback to print from within the same network). That being said, I really wouldn't advise you do this, but I wonder if anyone does!

Comment: those are my first thoughts as well.  unless by "wifi" the OP really means "bluetooth", in which case the answer's still "no... but".  :)

Comment: just 'cos I see there's a freeware program for allowing remote web printing on usb printers attached to a lan via an actual workstation.  Wondered if it was common to print over the internet to network attached printers.  ~quack can you expand on the bluetooth thing?  Why would it be any different to a usb printer for example?

Comment: a bluetooth printer wouldn't be different than USB, you'd need it attached to a workstation on the network to print to it, and you'd need to forward ports on the router to print from across the internet.  a network printer provides a mini workstation-on-the-network (called a "print server") -- you still need to forward ports, but you don't need to leave your home workstation on just to print.

Comment: ok dokes - for a bonus point anyone know any software out there that 'talks' to remotely located wifi printer servers?

Comment: The correct drivers that come with the printer or updated from the website?

Comment: your access point's wifi stack?  ;)